# When I am defining the URL patterns in django version 2.1.4 , I am getting an error. please show me a path

Tags: python, django, web-deployment, web-deployment-project

I am trying to run the web application named test app.I have imported all the modules correctly and crosschecked them.The error is below with the code.
Error on running the project from CMD:
path('about/',views.about),
AttributeError: module 'testapp.views' has no attribute 'about'

URLs.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from testapp import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('about/',views.about),]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
def about(request):
    s="<h1> This is an about page</h1>"
    return HttpResponse(s)
```

Comment: It is `views.py`, not `view.py` (so with an `s` at the end).

Comment: I know. I have used that in my code but I am still getting the error. could you help me figure it out

Comment: Was testapp created using "python manage.py startapp testapp" ? Are urls.py and views.py both in your testapp directory ?

Comment: The name of my project is firstproject which is created using django-admin startproject firstproject. Inside the firstproject I created testapp using python manage.py startapp testapp. URLs.py is in firstproject and views.py is in testapp. Could you help me find the error.

Comment: I've cut and pasted your code into a new django project and it worked when I navigated to http://127.0.0.1:8000/about/. Does the error occur when you run "python manage.py runserver" or when you navigate to the URL ?

Comment: Could you please tell me the Django and python versions you are using.

Comment: Sure, Python 3.8.5 and Django 3.1.2. How are you creating and activating your virtual environment?

Comment: No it occurrs when I type python manage.py runserver

Comment: I have uninstalled python python and django and downloading the latest versions.

Comment: I am using Atom ide. I am a beginner

Comment: Okay, it should work with just about any version though. How are you creating and activating your virtual environment? Any other errors being displayed?

Comment: Thanks alot for your help . I am downloading the latest version.

Comment: I don't know about virtual environment. I am just using Atom ide.

Comment: Okay, when you get time investigate Python virtual environments. There are many ways to do them but I recommend using pipenv. Virtual environments allow you to install different Python packages for each Python project. It doesn't matter which IDE you are using.

Comment: Sure sir, I will do it!